# Ordering Pairs of Data by date - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am somewhat new to coding in Pandas and I have what I think to be a simple problem that I can't find an answer to. I have a list of students, the college they went to and what year they entered college.

| Name | College | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | Princeton | 2017 |
| Joe | Harvard | 2018 |
| Bill | Princeton | 2016 |
| Louise | Princeton | 2020 |
| Michael | Harvard | 2019 |
| Penny | Yale | 2018 |
| Harry | Yale | 2015 |

I need the data to be ordered by year but grouped by college. However, if I order by year then I get the years in order but the colleges not together and if I order by college then I get the colleges together in alphabetical order but not with the years in order. Similarly if I order by year then college I won't get the colleges together and if I order by college then year I can't guarantee that the most recent year is first. What I want the table to look like is:

| Name | College | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Louise | Princeton | 2020 |
| Mary | Princeton | 2017 |
| Bill | Princeton | 2016 |
| Michael | Harvard | 2019 |
| Joe | Harvard | 2018 |
| Penny | Yale | 2018 |
| Harry | Yale | 2015 |

So we see Princeton is first because it has the most recent year, but all the Princeton colleges are all together. Than Harvard is next because 2019>2018 which is the most recent year for Yale so it has the two Harvard schools. Followed by Yale since 2020>2019>2018. I appreciate all your ideas and help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add a temporary extra column with the max year per group and sort on multiple columns:

```
out = (df
 .assign(max_year=df.groupby('College')['Year'].transform('max'))
 .sort_values(by=['max_year', 'College', 'Year'], ascending=[False, True, False])
 .drop(columns='max_year')
)
```

output:

```
      Name    College  Year
3   Louise  Princeton  2020
0     Mary  Princeton  2017
2     Bill  Princeton  2016
4  Michael    Harvard  2019
1      Joe    Harvard  2018
5    Penny       Yale  2018
6    Harry       Yale  2015
```

with temporary column:

```
      Name    College  Year  max_year
3   Louise  Princeton  2020      2020
0     Mary  Princeton  2017      2020
2     Bill  Princeton  2016      2020
4  Michael    Harvard  2019      2019
1      Joe    Harvard  2018      2019
5    Penny       Yale  2018      2018
6    Harry       Yale  2015      2018
```

Answer (score 1):

You first want to sort by `"College"` then `"Year"`, then keep `"College"` values together by using `.groupby`

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ["Mary", "Princeton", 2017],
    ["Joe", "Harvard", 2018],
    ["Bill", "Princeton", 2016],
    ["Louise", "Princeton", 2020],
    ["Michael", "Harvard", 2019],
    ["Penny", "Yale", 2018],
    ["Harry", "Yale", 2015],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name", "College", "Year"])
df.sort_values(["College", "Year"], ascending=False).groupby("College").head()
```

You'd get this output:

```
   Name    College  Year
  Penny       Yale  2018
  Harry       Yale  2015
 Louise  Princeton  2020
   Mary  Princeton  2017
   Bill  Princeton  2016
Michael    Harvard  2019
    Joe    Harvard  2018
```

Comment: So I originally thought that this might be a solution, but it doesn't guarantee that the group of Princeton students will be first. This gives Yale first in the output and if you switch the order of college and year in the input, than the colleges are no longer grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to first find the maximum among each group and set that as a column.
You can then sort by values based on max and year.

```
df=pd.read_table('./table.txt')
df["max"]=df.groupby("College")["Year"].transform("max")
df.sort_values(by=["max","Year"],ascending=False).drop(columns="max").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
Out[60]:
      Name    College  Year
0   Louise  Princeton  2020
1     Mary  Princeton  2017
2     Bill  Princeton  2016
3  Michael    Harvard  2019
4      Joe    Harvard  2018
5    Penny       Yale  2018
6    Harry       Yale  2015
```